# Como adicionar parâmetros permitidos globalmente no Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Em diversos resources utilizo endereço, decidi alocar a lógica em concerns. Uma necessidade é adicionar os parâmetros permitidos o endereço, veja abaixo o concern que deveria adicionar permissão para `address_attributes`:

```
module AddressationConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :address_params
  end

  protected

  def address_params
    params.permit address_attributes: [
      :zip_code, :state, :neighborhood, :city, :street, :number, :complement
    ]
  end
end
```

Como qualquer concern, faço a chamada ao topo da controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include AddressationConcern

  ...

  private

  ...

  def user_params
    params.fetch(:user, {}).permit :name, :cpf, :email, :password
  end
end
```

A questão está na segunda chamada de `params.permit` onde sobrescrevo a contida dentro do concern.

Desconheço uma forma de efetivar esse tipo de lógica. Algum colega conhece uma forma de efetivar isso?

Obrigado!

Comment: `AddressationConcern` é um concern das controllers, deixando isso bem claro aqui.

Comment: Como os parâmetros vão ser usados? Teoricamente cada _params método tem um retorno diferente então é possível você justar os dois quando estiver usando.

Comment: Saquei. A ideia era somente isolar `address_attributes` em um concern e assim não ter que ficar repetindo isso em cada resource que o utilize. Mas você está certo, pode ser que tenhamos parâmetro diferentes em método diferentes e nesse caso não se aplica isso. Agora se pudesse existir uma forma de informar que aquele grupo (address_attributes) é global, isso, acredito eu, poderia ter diversas aplicações. Mas é uma ideia, posso estar errado.

Comment: Levantei essa questão com o intuito de entender se é possível, mas a forma simples é ter `address_attributes` definido em cada controller que assim for utilizar-lo. Me encanta a forma como os concerns podem auxiliar no encapsulamento de lógica repetida.

Comment: @rafaelfranca obrigado pelas dicas, a solução que postei abaixo resolve a questão, talvez existam melhores formas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A melhor alternativa que encontrei, atendendo a minha necessidade que é abstrair os parâmetro de endereço aos quais utilizo em diversos resources foi criar um modulo retornando um array com os atributos, veja abaixo:

```
module AddressationConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  protected

  def address_attributes
    [:zip_code, :state, :neighborhood, :city, :street, :number, :complement]
  end
end
```

Faço a chamada do método em `user_params`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include AddressationConcern

  ...

  private

  ...

  def user_params
    params.fetch(:user, {}).permit(
      :name, :cpf, :email, :password,
      address_attributes: address_attributes
    )
  end
end
```

Conversei com diversos colegas e amigos sobre essa abordagem. A gem `strong_parameters` é fantástica, esse tipo de abstração é desnecessária, porem a quis implementa-lá por questões de perfeccionismo.